# Parsing a flat XML document in Kotlin

Tags: java, xml, parsing, kotlin, xml-parsing

I'm dealing with a poorly structured XML scheme in a little personal project, and am stuck on an elegant way to parse out elements from what should be hierarchical but is instead a flat data structure. My document looks something like this:

```xml
<resources>
  <category type="first" />
  <item name="foo" />
  <item name="bar" />
  <item name="baz" />

  <category type="second" />
  <item name="qux" />
  <item name="fizz" />

  ...
</resources>
```

Ideally I'd end up with this as a `Map<String, List<String>>` where the Keys are the category types and the Values are the lists of item names. The `org.w3c.dom` APIs are just...terrible to use, from a beginner's perspective.

How can I do this? Are there better XML parsing libraries out there?

Comment: This style of XML is more common that you might think, unfortunately. You could transform it using XSL into a format that you like, and then write simpler Java.